# Multi-language support

Tags: sql-server, localization, diacritics

We have developed a site that needs to display text in English, Polish, Slovak and Czech. However, when the text is entered into the database, any accented letters are changed to english letters.

After searching around on forums, I have found that it is possible to put an 'N' in front of a string which contains accented characters. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name (Col1, Col2) VALUES (N'Value1', N'Value2')
```

However, the site has already been fully developed so at this stage, going through all of the INSERT and UPDATE queries in the site would be a very long and tedious process.

I was wondering if there is any other, much quicker, way of doing what I am trying to do?

The database is MSSQL and the columns being inserted into are already nvarchar(n).

Comment: How do you access the database? (What type of clients?)

Comment: What are the column definitions? Are you using NVARCHAR types instead of VARCHAR?

Comment: @Stu Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. The site is a .NET site if that's what you mean?

Comment: @Oded The datatypes are nvarchar

Comment: So are you manually creating INSERT and UPDATE statements in strings?

Comment: What collation is defined on these columns and the database as a whole? Also, could you post the code that does the insert (I am assuming this is done from an application)?

Comment: @Stu In most cases, unfortunately, it is inline SQL, yes. It's a site that was started over a year ago when I was very new to ASP.NET programming so the vast majority of the SQL statements are inline. There are also a few stored procedures as well though.

Comment: @Oded The collation for the database as a whole is Latin1_General_CI_AS. I haven't changed the collation individually for any columns or tables so I assume the collation is the same across the whole database. One example of an INSERT statement where letters with accents could be entered is: db.Open.Update("INSERT INTO BannedWords (Word) VALUES (N'" + Word + "')", Conn). (db.Open.Update is just an old function that we used to use to simply create a sqlcommand object and then executenonquery.)

Comment: @Leah - apart from the fact that this code appears to be open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it would appear to be OK. Did you debug into it and check that `Word` is indeed what you expect and has the accents?

Comment: @Oded This code is in the admin area so in this case, I think I'm right in thinking that it should be safe from SQL injection attacks, although I am aware that it would be far better done using parameters now. I've just realised that in my example that I pasted in my comment, 'N' is already preceding 'Word'. The accents are retained when 'N' is preceding the word but this is the one place in my code that 'N' has been added, because I added it to test if it works. If I remove 'N', the accents are not retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any quick solution.

The updates and inserts are wrong and need to be fixed.

If they were parameterized queries, you could have simply made sure they were using the NVarChar database type and you would not have a problem.

Since they are dynamic strings, you will need to ensure that you add the unicode specifier (`N`) in front of each text field you are inserting/updating.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this. I have tried changing one of my inline SQL statements to a stored procedure with parameters, and I can confirm that using parameters does retain the accents. Looks like I've got a tedious job ahead....

Answer (score 0):

Topic-starter wrote:

> "text in English, Polish, Slovak and Czech. However, when the text is entered into the database, any accented letters are changed to english letters" After searching around on forums, I have found that it is possible to put an 'N' in front of a string which contains accented characters. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name (Col1, Col2) VALUES (N'Value1', N'Value2')
```

> "The collation for the database as a whole is Latin1_General_CI_AS"

I do not see how it could happen due to SQL Server since  Latin1_General_CI_AS treats european "non-English" letters:

```
--on database with collation Latin1_General_CI_AS
declare @test_multilanguage_eu table
(
     c1 char(12),
     c2 nchar(12)
)

INSERT INTO @test_multilanguage_eu  VALUES ('éÉâÂàÀëËçæà', 'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà')

SELECT c1, cast(c1 as binary(4)) as c1bin, c2, cast(c2 as binary(4)) as c2bin 
FROM @test_multilanguage_eu
```

outputs:

```
c1           c1bin      c2           c2bin
------------ ---------- ------------ ----------
éÉâÂàÀëËçæà  0xE9C9E2C2 éÉâÂàÀëËçæà  0xE900C900
```

(1 row(s) affected)

I believe you simply have to check checkboxes them Control Panel --> Regional and Language Options  --> tab Advanced -->  Code page conversion tables and check that you render in the same codepage as you store it.
Converting to unicode from encodings used by clients would lead to problems to render back to webclients,  it seems to me.

I believe that most European collation designators use codepage 1252 [1], [2].

Update:
SELECT
    COLLATIONPROPERTY('Latin1_General_CI_AS' , 'CodePage') 
 outputs 1252

[1]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596.aspx
[2]
Windows 1252
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145.aspx